# Binary Voltage relation to endian

Tags: binary, endianness

Lately, I have been studying 6502 microprocessor and came across the fact that binary and voltage relate. 0 for 0volts and 1 for 5 volts.

Now I just recently learned about endian-ness as well. So trying to learn more about both of these topics I was wondering if someone could explain the relation of binary/voltage and the little or big endian.

If there really isn't a difference because 00000001 would only use 5 volts and 10000000 would only used 5 volts as well. Then I am sorry for asking a useless topic. Now if that is the case, please share some more interesting knowledge about endian-ness, binary
and/or Voltage.

Unfortunately I don't have university experience so i am unsure if this is common knowledge, but thanks for any information that you provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're not very related.

When you have a voltmeter and you read a single bit, a 0-volt would correspond to a 0, and a 5-volt would correspond to a 1.  Or you could say "high voltage is 1, and low voltage is 0".

Now, to represent a number, let's simply say that we use powers of 2:

- 1 = 001
- 2 = 010
- 3 = 011
- 4 = 100
- 5 = 101

And so on.  However, what I just used is little-endian: the end bit (the one on the right) is small, it represents 1 (if it's 1) or 0 (if it's 0), as opposed to the bit on the left (4 if it's 1, 0 if it's 0).  If we flipped the order around, that would be big-endian.

You could think of each bit (each 0 or 1) as a different wire with either 0 or 5 volts on it.

Comment: Ah just as i thought. Well interesting to know I guess. Well i guess if your willing to answer. Can i get 2.5 volts from a bit? If so can you tell me what that is called so i can read about it.

Comment: Bits always go from low to high, endianness refers to the way bytes are combined to form 16-bit words and 32-bit longwords.

Comment: @John Riselvato 2.5 volts would be ambiguous.  It would really depend on the hardware to determine whether it represents a 0 or a 1, and is a result of bad circuit design (hooking up P- and N- junctions in the wrong order).